# Get notification when user updated on Azure AD using MS Graph

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-webhooks

I am trying to get notification when user is updated on MS  Azure  AD using MS Graph and Web hook.I have tried [microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-changenotifications](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-changenotifications/tree/master/demos/03-track-changes) but face following

> Status Code: Unauthorized
> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ExtensionError
> Message: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Unauthorized; Reason: ]

I have also explore [notifications for changes in user data](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample) this code but it is for "Mail.Read" permission and I want to "User.Read" permission .

My case/issue is like [Not receiving a request on our MS Graph Webbook for deleting a User in AAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904620/not-receiving-a-request-on-our-ms-graph-webhook-for-deleting-a-user-in-aad) but something different. i need notification on update user on my asp.net core project.

**Please help me. I am troubling since last 3 days but not getting proper solution**

Answer (score 0):

I was missing to give a permission in Azure AD

> User.ReadWrite.All

I have watched this video [Change notifications with Microsoft Graph](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fThiCZmIcMQ) and use this code [msgraph-training-changenotifications](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-changenotifications) .**Now i got notification from Azure AD** [image]